# Swipe down keyboard's QuickType bar button to hide keyboard in iOS

Tags: ios, keyboard, hide, quicktypebar

I'm editing UITextView in landscape mode, where keyboard is appeared with QuickType bar. If QuickType bar is hidden, is there any workaround to implement the exact functionality as shown in below image.

[image]

Thank you !